# Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

```
>>> def clockwise(r):
...     return list(r[0]) + clockwise(list(reversed(zip(*r[1:])))) if r else []
... 
>>> a = [ 
...   [ 1,  2,  3], 
...   [ 5,  6,  7], 
...   [ 9, 10, 11]]
>>> clockwise(a)
[1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 10, 9, 5, 6]
```

I'm trying to change the function clockwise into Javascript but can't seem to get it to work.

I've created some methods with similar functions:

```
function zip(masterArray){//zips 2 arrays
var innerLoop = masterArray.length; //inner loop
var outerLoop = 0;
//get length of shortest
for (var i = 0; i<masterArray.length;i++){
    var a = masterArray[i].length;
    if (outerLoop==0){outerLoop = a;}else if(a < outerLoop){outerLoop = a;}
}

var newOuterArray = new Array(outerLoop);
    for (var x = 0; x<outerLoop;x++){
        var newInnerArray = new Array(innerLoop);
            for (var y = 0; y<innerLoop;y++){
                newInnerArray[y] = masterArray[y][x];
                }
            newOuterArray[x] = newInnerArray;
}
 return newOuterArray;
}

function reversed(arr){
    var newArray = new Array(arr.length);
    var n = 0;
    for(var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        newArray[n++] = arr[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}

function clockwise(r){

    if(r.length>0){
            var a = reversed(zip(r.slice(1)));
            a.splice(0,0,r[0]);
            return clockwise(a);
     }else{
        return [];
    }
}
```

Here's my progress. I'm stuck at the last part: clockwise error in firebug is too much recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the use of splice.  Try something like this instead...

```
function clockwise(r){
    if(r.length>0){
        var remaining = r.slice(1)
        var a = reversed(zip(remaining));
        return r[0].concat(clockwise(a));
     } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the recursive call to `clockwise()` to be before you prepend `r[0]` otherwise you never get down to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what the algorithm is trying to do, but the Javascript version of clockwise looks like it can only ever return [].  There are two return paths.  One calls clockwise, the other returns [] so the only way out of that function is to return [].  That's not how your python version works.

I haven't looked at reversed and zip, but there is a logic difference in the javascript version of clockwise.  In the javascript version, you remove the first item in the array, then reverse and zip, then put the first item back on the array and call clockwise on the whole thing.  In the Python version, you remvoe the first item in the array, call clocks and reverse on only the item without the first version, then add the first one back on afterwards.  Very different logic.  The Python version is much more likely to end.

I haven't looked at the other functions reverse and zip, but this looks like a more faithful javascript version of clockwise:

```
function clockwise(r) {
    if (r.length > 0) {
        var a = clockwise(reversed(zip(r.slice(1))));   // call clockwise on array starting at index 1
        a.splice(0,0,r[0]);                             // put first value in original array back onto the beginning of the result
        return (a);                                     // return new array
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```